# Media players for Windows optimized for TV screen

Tags: windows, media-player

Sometimes, I like to connect my laptop to Television using HDMI and watch content stored on my Hard Disk.

I typically set the content scale to Highest in Windows settings. But this is not enough. Content still looks tiny when I look at Television from a distance.

So I am looking for a media player. Features I am looking for are:

1. Support for Windows.
2. Big buttons, interface so things are readable from distance.
3. Large codec support
4. Built-in file manager optimized for TV so I can see the content on my storage there.

Answer (score 2):

[Kodi](https://kodi.tv/) is a media player and media library management software with a 10 foot interface optimized for using with TV sets and standalone hardware media player boxes.

It runs on a variety of hardware and operating systems including but not limited to Windows, Mac Linux, Android, Raspberry Pi among others.

It can be used with windows compatible remote controls or wirelessly through a mobile [companion app for Android phones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kore).

It might require some setting up, or manual browsing, but if you bother to configure recurring folders as permanent library it can easy navigating content using an interface designed for operation on TVs.

[image]